# Active Directory Web Service and AutoCompleteExtender

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, ajaxcontroltoolkit

This is my first time playing with Active Directory, as well as the Ajax Control Toolkit. What I'm trying to do is when a user starts to type their name in a textbox, it will attempt to auto-complete their name as listed in AD. Every example I can find on using the AutoCompleteExtender, it's referring to an ASMX file in the ServicePath.

I've managed to figure out how to add our AD web service as a service reference to my project.
Can anyone provide any guidance or examples on how I can get AutoCompleteExtender to recognize and play with my AD service reference? Is it even possible?

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: just curious, what is the use of this? you describe it as if you want to assist a user to enter her own username ("a user starts to type THEIR name"). if the user is authenticated already, there is no need for her to enter the name, it can be retrieved via the authentication information. if the user is not authenticated yet (as on a logon page), this autocompletion would leak sensitive information (all names in AD) to unauthenticated clients.

Comment: This is for internal user only. The user would be entering in, not only their own name, but the name of fellow employees as well. They already have access to this information via Outlook; I'm just trying to make it easier for them to fill out the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research and help from our system admins to get the correct LDAP path, I've finally got this working. I'm posting the code so other's can benefit from it. (Note that I first installed AJAX Control Toolkit for .NET 4.0.)

**Default.aspx:**

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="True"></ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearchAD" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender ServiceMethod="findEmp"
MinimumPrefixLength="3"
CompletionInterval="100"
EnableCaching="true"
CompletionSetCount="10"
TargetControlID="txtSearchAD"
ID="ace1"
runat="server"
FirstRowSelected="false" ServicePath="ADS.asmx">
</ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

**ADS.asmx.cs:**

```
namespace EventTracking
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for ADS
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]

    public class ADS : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string[] findEmp(string prefixText, int count)
        {            
            DirectoryEntry directory = new DirectoryEntry();
            directory.Path = "LDAP://DC=yourdomain,DC=com";  //CHANGE to your LDAP path
            string filter = "(&(cn=" + prefixText + "*))";
            string[] strCats = { "cn" };
            List<string> items = new List<string>();
            DirectorySearcher dirComp = new DirectorySearcher(directory, filter, strCats, SearchScope.Subtree);
            SearchResultCollection results = dirComp.FindAll();
            foreach (SearchResult result in results)
            {
                foreach (DictionaryEntry prop in result.Properties)
                {
                    if (prop.Key.Equals("cn"))
                    {
                        System.Collections.IEnumerable propsEnum = prop.Value as System.Collections.IEnumerable;
                        foreach (object individualValue in propsEnum)
                        {
                            if (individualValue.ToString().IndexOf(prefixText) != 0)
                            {
                                items.Add(individualValue.ToString());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return items.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Side note...  I was receiving too much data from AD that I didn't need... server names, etc. If you need to filter the data coming back from your AD, you can add an "Organizational Unit" to the path as such:  LDAP://OU=ADusers,DC=yourdomain,DC=com

Comment: prop.Key.Equals("cn") ? I dont can use Key :(