# How I can use the Active Directory for AutoComplete in a Webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, autocomplete, active-directory

I want built a ASP.NET Application with a AutoComplete with Ajax. I want use the Active Directory to get Data how Displayname.

Here my Code:

ASPX:

```
    <tr>
            <td><asp:Label ID="lblVertreter" runat="server" /></td>
            <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtVertreter" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoComlete" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtVertreter" ServiceMethod="MitarbeiterErmitelln" ServicePath="Service1.asmx"></asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
            AutoCompleteExtender
            </td>
</tr>
```

asmx code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Data;
using System.DirectoryServices;

namespace ADWebService
{

    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]

    public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        public static string GetLdapProperty(SearchResult searchResult, string PropertyName)
        {

            if (searchResult.Properties.Contains(PropertyName))
            {
                return searchResult.Properties[PropertyName][0].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }

        }

        [WebMethod]
        public string[] MitarbeiterErmitelln(string prefix)
        {
            string filterung = "((&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=user)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)(sn=*)(|(telephoneNumber=*)(mail=*))(displayName=*" + prefix + "*)))";

            string ADPfad = "Domain";

            int Counter = 0;

            List<Benutzer> result = new List<Benutzer>();

            DirectoryEntry Entry = new DirectoryEntry(ADPfad);

            DirectorySearcher Searcher = new DirectorySearcher(Entry, filterung);

            foreach (SearchResult usr in Searcher.FindAll())
            {
                result.Add(new Benutzer()
                {
                    DisplayName = GetLdapProperty(usr, "displayName"),

                });
                Counter++;
            }

            return result.ToArray(); 
        }

    }
}

//The Class Benutzer is my Model Class
```

What is wrong. I want use direct the Active Directory !

Comment: Could you provide the exception, or error. Because you posted the code, but haven't written the problem.

Comment: Why don't you use J-query instead of AutoCompleteExtender?

Comment: return result.ToArray();  is wrong ....I see for a few minutes a other Post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11129769/active-directory-web-service-and-autocompleteextender but there I get a Error by prop.Key.Equals("cn"). :(

Comment: Have you looked into using a BindingList